# Base64 output differs when encoding from file vs string

Tags: node.js, string, utf-8, base64, fs

I'm trying to base64 encode a S3 policy string according [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) example but my code is not returning the expected value when I assign the policy string to a variable using a template literal.

However, it works if I copy/paste the exact same string and then read the file with `fs`. I can even base64 encode the literal string, get the wrong value, decode the wrong value, paste the decoded string into a file, and encode the string (using fs) and get the expected result.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const policyString =`{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}`
const base64FromFile = fs.readFileSync('path/to/policy.txt')
console.log("String1:", base64FromFile.toString('base64'))
const base64FromString = Buffer(policyString).toString('base64')
console.log("String2:", base64FromString)
```

Here are the results. Notice that the strings are different.

```
String1 (Expected. From file.):

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

String2 (Incorrect. From string variable):
 eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE1LTEyLTMwVDEyOjAwOjAwLjAwMFoiLAogICJjb25kaXRpb25zIjogWwogICAgeyJidWNrZXQiOiAic2lndjRleGFtcGxlYnVja2V0In0sCiAgICBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRrZXkiLCAidXNlci91c2VyMS8iXSwKICAgIHsiYWNsIjogInB1YmxpYy1yZWFkIn0sCiAgICB7InN1Y2Nlc3NfYWN0aW9uX3JlZGlyZWN0IjogImh0dHA6Ly9zaWd2NGV4YW1wbGVidWNrZXQuczMuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbS9zdWNjZXNzZnVsX3VwbG9hZC5odG1sIn0sCiAgICBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiLCAiaW1hZ2UvIl0sCiAgICB7IngtYW16LW1ldGEtdXVpZCI6ICIxNDM2NTEyMzY1MTI3NCJ9LAogICAgeyJ4LWFtei1zZXJ2ZXItc2lkZS1lbmNyeXB0aW9uIjogIkFFUzI1NiJ9LAogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkeC1hbXotbWV0YS10YWciLCAiIl0sCgogICAgeyJ4LWFtei1jcmVkZW50aWFsIjogIkFLSUFJT1NGT0ROTjdFWEFNUExFLzIwMTUxMjI5L3VzLWVhc3QtMS9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QifSwKICAgIHsieC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIjogIkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSwKICAgIHsieC1hbXotZGF0ZSI6ICIyMDE1MTIyOVQwMDAwMDBaIiB9CiAgXQp9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I get the correct base64 string when I replace all linefeeds characters with crlf. It's odd because it appears to directly contradict the documentation but it gets me the correct results.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with how new lines are represented. Which operating system are you using? Also, which IDE and which text editor?

Comment: Mojave 10.14.5 and VSCode. If I run the following on the policyString before encoding, I get the expected result.

`policyString.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n')`